# Jenkins GraphErrorException using BitBucket pipeline

Tags: jenkins, azure-active-directory, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket

We use Jenkins (on Windows) as CI/CD tool and after renewing the app-registration token in Azure (we use AzureAD for authentication in Jenkins) we get a GraphErrorException in our bitbucket pipeline (see the log).

It seems that Jenkins tries to get the author of the commit and that this fails. Does anybody know which credentials the token exactly needs? And why the default rights are not sufficient?

Right now we have the following permissions in Azure:

[image]

This is the Jenkins log:

```
Started by user Laurens van Run - MendriX
Running as SYSTEM
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Start-Next-Root2
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential b9a23fe5-fb1c-436f-b971-6b691d7693fa
 > git.exe rev-parse --resolve-git-dir C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Start-Next-Root2\.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git.exe config remote.origin.url https://bitbucket.org/mendrix-next/_root.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://bitbucket.org/mendrix-next/_root.git
 > git.exe --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.26.2.windows.1'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials techsupport Bitbucket login
 > git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://bitbucket.org/mendrix-next/_root.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision dda42f2b63cec667c550b632956e78e1f70b5562 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git.exe checkout -f dda42f2b63cec667c550b632956e78e1f70b5562 # timeout=10
Commit message: "Auto updated @mendrixeu/dossier@1.0.307"
 > git.exe rev-list --no-walk dda42f2b63cec667c550b632956e78e1f70b5562 # timeout=10
FATAL: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: com.microsoft.azure.management.graphrbac.GraphErrorException: Status code 403, {"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."},"requestId":"d039b2b5-dc01-459d-92a4-6f69c01ea727","date":"2021-04-13T08:34:14"}}
com.microsoft.azure.management.graphrbac.GraphErrorException: Status code 403, {"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."},"requestId":"d039b2b5-dc01-459d-92a4-6f69c01ea727","date":"2021-04-13T08:34:14"}}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.rest.ServiceResponseBuilder.build(ServiceResponseBuilder.java:122)
    at com.microsoft.azure.AzureResponseBuilder.build(AzureResponseBuilder.java:56)
    at com.microsoft.azure.management.graphrbac.implementation.UsersInner.getDelegate(UsersInner.java:464)
    at com.microsoft.azure.management.graphrbac.implementation.UsersInner.access$200(UsersInner.java:43)
    at com.microsoft.azure.management.graphrbac.implementation.UsersInner$16.call(UsersInner.java:451)
    at com.microsoft.azure.management.graphrbac.implementation.UsersInner$16.call(UsersInner.java:447)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:69)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallArbiter.deliverResponse(CallArbiter.java:120)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallArbiter.emitResponse(CallArbiter.java:102)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallExecuteOnSubscribe.call(CallExecuteOnSubscribe.java:46)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallExecuteOnSubscribe.call(CallExecuteOnSubscribe.java:24)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10423)
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10390)
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:443)
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.single(BlockingObservable.java:340)
    at com.microsoft.azure.management.graphrbac.implementation.ActiveDirectoryUsersImpl.getByName(ActiveDirectoryUsersImpl.java:80)
    at com.microsoft.azure.management.graphrbac.implementation.ActiveDirectoryUsersImpl.getByName(ActiveDirectoryUsersImpl.java:25)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.azuread.AzureSecurityRealm.lambda$null$4(AzureSecurityRealm.java:319)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4870)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3524)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2273)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2156)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2046)
Caused: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2052)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3943)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4865)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.azuread.AzureSecurityRealm.lambda$createSecurityComponents$5(AzureSecurityRealm.java:312)
    at hudson.security.SecurityRealm.loadUserByUsername2(SecurityRealm.java:410)
    at jenkins.security.UserDetailsCache$Retriever.call(UserDetailsCache.java:165)
    at jenkins.security.UserDetailsCache$Retriever.call(UserDetailsCache.java:154)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4767)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3568)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2350)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2313)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2228)
Caused: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2234)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3965)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4764)
    at jenkins.security.UserDetailsCache.loadUserByUsername(UserDetailsCache.java:122)
    at hudson.model.User$UserIDCanonicalIdResolver.resolveCanonicalId(User.java:1246)
    at hudson.model.User$CanonicalIdResolver.resolve(User.java:1187)
    at hudson.model.User.get(User.java:520)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitChangeSet.findOrCreateUser(GitChangeSet.java:447)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitChangeSet.getAuthor(GitChangeSet.java:538)
    at jenkins.scm.RunWithSCM.calculateCulprits(RunWithSCM.java:137)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.calculateCulprits(AbstractBuild.java:342)
    at jenkins.scm.RunWithSCM.getCulprits(RunWithSCM.java:95)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getCulprits(AbstractBuild.java:331)
    at jenkins.scm.RunWithSCM.calculateCulprits(RunWithSCM.java:132)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.calculateCulprits(AbstractBuild.java:342)
    at jenkins.scm.RunWithSCM.getCulprits(RunWithSCM.java:95)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getCulprits(AbstractBuild.java:331)
    at jenkins.scm.RunWithSCM.calculateCulprits(RunWithSCM.java:132)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.calculateCulprits(AbstractBuild.java:342)
    at jenkins.scm.RunWithSCM.getCulprits(RunWithSCM.java:95)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getCulprits(AbstractBuild.java:331)
    at jenkins.scm.RunWithSCM.calculateCulprits(RunWithSCM.java:132)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.calculateCulprits(AbstractBuild.java:342)
    at jenkins.scm.RunWithSCM.getCulprits(RunWithSCM.java:95)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getCulprits(AbstractBuild.java:331)
    at jenkins.scm.RunWithSCM.calculateCulprits(RunWithSCM.java:132)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.calculateCulprits(AbstractBuild.java:342)
    at jenkins.scm.RunWithSCM.getCulprits(RunWithSCM.java:95)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getCulprits(AbstractBuild.java:331)
    at jenkins.scm.RunWithSCM.calculateCulprits(RunWithSCM.java:132)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.calculateCulprits(AbstractBuild.java:342)
    at jenkins.scm.RunWithSCM.getCulprits(RunWithSCM.java:95)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getCulprits(AbstractBuild.java:331)
    at jenkins.scm.RunWithSCM.calculateCulprits(RunWithSCM.java:132)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.calculateCulprits(AbstractBuild.java:342)
    at jenkins.scm.RunWithSCM.getCulprits(RunWithSCM.java:95)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getCulprits(AbstractBuild.java:331)
    at jenkins.scm.RunWithSCM.calculateCulprits(RunWithSCM.java:132)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.calculateCulprits(AbstractBuild.java:342)
    at jenkins.scm.RunWithSCM.getCulprits(RunWithSCM.java:95)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getCulprits(AbstractBuild.java:331)
    at jenkins.scm.RunWithSCM.calculateCulprits(RunWithSCM.java:132)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.calculateCulprits(AbstractBuild.java:342)
    at jenkins.scm.RunWithSCM.getCulprits(RunWithSCM.java:95)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getCulprits(AbstractBuild.java:331)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:701)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1931)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: What are the permissions you added into app registration? Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: I have updated the post with a screenshot.

Comment: Permissions look good. Can you share the code where the error is thrown? I need to know how you get the access token and which API endpoint you are trying to call.

Answer (score 0):

This was all caused by a bug in Jenkins and the Jenkins Azure AD plugin which was solved last week (just a day after posting this issue ;-)). Thanks for your help!